file not found with PyInstaller and Django
I'm using PyInstaller for a Django application, with some difficulties I was able to generate the .exe file and the application starts, but when I try to see any page I get TemplateDoesNotExist error.
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\path\to\project\dist\vale_remote\_internal\src\dashboard\templates\dashboard\pages\dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\path\to\project\dist\vale_remote\_internal\src\interview\templates\dashboard\pages\dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\path\to\project\dist\vale_remote\_internal\src\vale_remote\templates\dashboard\pages\dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\path\to\project\dist\vale_remote\_internal\django\contrib\admin\templates\dashboard\pages\dashboard.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\path\to\project\dist\vale_remote\_internal\django\contrib\auth\templates\dashboard\pages\dashboard.html (Source does not exist)


If i go to '_internal' folder i see no 'src' folder, I don't know if I have to change the path to the templates or I should create this src folder somehow. In my 'normal' folder structure (not the PyInstaller generated) the template django is looking for is in project/dashboard/templates/dashboard/pages/dashboard.html
